# dmidecode uuid is different from Vmware esxi server

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, dmidecode

I have a query related to dmidecode uuid. In our product we are using dmidecode uuid try to match with ESXI vmware uuid of the same node.

ESXI is providing the UUID as first three fields as big endian format.

But in dmidecode for smbios version 2.6 onwards it changes it format of first three field in little endian.

So do we need to follow Vmware ESXI standard or do we need to align to dmidecode standard.

our product supports other hypervisors Hyper-V, KVM .

If we align to ESXI format, we need to convert the little endian of dmidecode to Big endian in our product level.

Does Hper-v and KVM also follow same standard as Vmware ESXI (Big endian standarad) or not ?.

Comment: In KVM the UUID is entirely random. There is no correlation between UUID in two VMs, even on the same host.

Comment: Hi michael, Sorry for the confusion. My doubt here is does all the hypervisors supports dmidecode standard ?  I could see that when While getting the uuid of node from Vcenter ESXI it is having first three fields in diffferent order, when i compare the same in "dmidecode -s system-uuid" the byte order is different. having smbios version 2.6